# Why is water only coming through the handheld hose?

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, sink, hose

I have a hose at my kitchen sink, installed alongside the cold water faucet.  Every once in awhile when I press the hose trigger, it becomes stuck and will not return to the off position automatically, and water will not come out of the faucet. A few clicks of the trigger and it returns to normal.

Yesterday I used the hose ... only now it has not returned to off position. I've unscrewed the nozzle portion and see nothing that is clogged or jammed. With the nozzle head off, water still comes through the hose itself, leading me to believe that there is always water in the hose and that pressing the nozzle releases water that is already there.

Perhaps what is happening is that the nozzle is no longer "holding back" the water?

Answer (score 3):

You are correct in the fact that water is always present in the hose.  When you turn on the faucet water gets sent through a diverter valve, this valve splits the flow of water between the faucet and the hose.  It detects changes in pressure and adapts the flow accordingly.  If water is not flowing through your hose and it does not go back to the faucet then you most likely have an issue with your diverter.

Comment: Yep, diverter valve is first place I'd look. +vote